# The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Created A VIEW IN MY ASP.NET MVC APPLICATION.

View class retrieves a data of 6100 rows

that class is used in one of my view which fills grid with data it can also be  sorted.

it will load nicely for first time then sorting also works fine but when i click on last page link it takes time and finally gives following error

The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
anyone can help me please i am not getting WATS the problem

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the request time is reaching the max allowed (default in ASP.NET = 30 secs). I don't think its as the back button as much as the request is randomly taking 29 secs, 31 secs, etc.

You may want to try a pagination approach to displaying your data instead of loading 6,100 rows at once - this will reduce the load times.

Check out this [link](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm) for a pagination example.

Another idea would to use page caching. But I would recommend pagination.